# I have a problem with for-loop math; adding powers of two

Tags: c

I want to add powers of two, starting with 128 and working my way down to 1.
The addition happens with the push of a button, and when it is first pressed (1), I want to output 128. When it is pressed the second time (2), I want to output 128+64=192, and so on, and so forth.  Is my application of the math wrong, or is there maybe something else wrong? Thanks in advance!

Everything I've tried boils down to having two for-loops, one inside the other, with the inner loop generating a power of two, and the outer adding them.

```
int j, k;        //for-loop counters
int base = 2;    //number to exponentialize 
int d = 0, x = 1;  //output, and exponent helper respectively

for(j=buttonpresses; j>0; j--){            

   for(k=0; k<8-buttonpresses; k++){       

      x = x*base;                  

   }

   d = d + x;
   x = 1;
}

printf("%d", d);
```

I expect the output to be 128, then 192, then 224, and so on.
I never get that, but a variable output of stuff, depending on small stuff I change.

Comment: try replacing `buttonpresses` with `j` in your inner loop

Comment: "The addition happens with the push of a button". The code has no evidence of any such thing. "I expect the output to be 128, then 192" You have only one `printf` in your program, and it's outside of any loop.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use two nested loop? Because you don't need more then one loop (actually, none, but I guess that's not the purpose of the assignment).

Comment: @n.m. I didn't include the code that increments or decrements "buttonpress" because I didn't think it relevant to the problem.  It's simply always 1-8, with a value og 1 supposed to give the outcome 128, a value of 2 giving 192, and so on.

Comment: @Bob__ The assignment is completed, I used a simple Switch/Case setup.  I only posted this here because I really want to get my head around the mathematical solution to the problem.

Comment: @KarstenKoop That worked! Thank you so much! Can I bother you to explain to me why?

Comment: @ÓliSig consider the case `buttonpresses = 2`, on the first iteration `j = 2` which means `k < 8 - 2`, the result from `x = x*base` will be `2^6` and `d = d + x` will be `d = 0 + 64`, on the second iteration `j` is decremented and `j = 1` which means `k < 8 - 1`, the result will be `2^7` and `d = d + x` will be `d = 64 + 128`, `j` is decremented again `j > 0` is no longer true thus the loop ceases